# assign and allocate memory for a pointer inside a struct in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct

Suppose I have a struct:

```
struct b {
    unsigned short  num;
    unsigned short  size;
    unsigned char  *a;
};
```

I then declare a pointer that points to a `struct` of `b`:

```
struct b *foo=malloc(sizeof(struct b));
```

how do I allocate memory for `foo`'s `a` and assign `a` to point to a character string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that different, e.g, to allocate the memory for the string `hello`:

```
char *hello = "hello";
foo->a = malloc(strlen(hello) + 1);
strcpy(foo->a, hello);
```

Comment: why are you not using foo->a? Also, a is a pointer though, shouldn't it be foo.a = &hello; ?

Comment: @user3300198 It should be `foo->a`,that's my mistake, fixed now. `foo->a = hello` could work, but that means you are making `a` to point to that string, in that case, you don't need to allocate memory for `a`. It depends on what you need.

Comment: @user3300198 Continue: `strcpy` on the other hand, copies the contents of the string to `a`, and I assume it's what you want because you are asking about allocating memory for `a`. Again, it depends on what you need.

Comment: @user3300198 You can try it out, using the version of simple assignment `foo->a = hello` or the version using memory allocation and `strcpy`, then change the original string, see what happened between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `struct b *foo = malloc(sizeof *foo);` already allocates enough space to accomodate a char pointer, so it depends on what you want to do with `foo->a` (ps: because foo is a pointer, you need to use the indirection operator).

If `foo->a` (or, `*(foo).a`) can be a constant string, you can simply do this:

```
struct b *foo = malloc(sizeof *foo);
foo->a = "A constant string";
```

Note that, because this is (sort of) equivalent to:

```
const char *const_str = "this is read-only";
```

You can't change anything about the chars `a` points to. The member `a` is assigned an address of a string constant in read-only memory. In short:

```
foo->a = "constant";
printf("%c%c%c\n", foo->a[0], foo->a[2], foo->a[4]);//prints cnt 
foo->a[0] = 'C';//WRONG!
```

If you want to be able to change the string, use this:

```
foo->a = malloc(50 * sizeof *(foo->a)));
```

The `sizeof` is optional here, since the size of `char` is guaranteed to be size 1, always.
To assign/copy a string you use `strcat`, `strcpy`, `memcpy`, `strncat`, `sprintf` and the like

```
strcpy(foo->a, "constant");
printf("%c%c%c\n", foo->a[0], foo->a[2], foo->a[4]);//still prints cnt 
foo->a[0] = 'r';
printf("%c%c%c\n", foo->a[0], foo->a[2], foo->a[4]);//still prints rnt
```

Now you can change the string `a` points to, but as a result, you'll have to free this memory, too, when you're done with it:

```
//wrong:
free(foo);//works, but won't free the memory allocated for foo->a
//better:
free(foo->a);
free(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

'foo->a' (operator ->)should be used

Answer (score 0):

First you have to assign memory for foo by malloc, then it will contain the address of the inside pointer called "a". When you have the memory address of "a" (not the "pointed to" but the address where the pointed to address is stored), you can store addresses there.

so:
1. struct b *foo = malloc(...)
2. foo->a = malloc(...)